# Git Filter-branch doesn't remove folders?

Tags: shell, git-svn, git-rebase, git-filter-branch, unexpectendoffile

I wanted to convert most of my repositories from my own SVN-server onto a hosted remote Git-server. I found a [couple of commands](http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git) and turned them into an automated shell script in order to convert the repositories in a smoother way.

Anyhow, that all worked, but now I'm getting `unexpected EOF`-errors from the hosted server whenever I'm trying to clone the git repository to work on it. Some big repositories (2 - 10 Gigs) take too long to import...

So I tried to use `filter-branch` for [removing folders](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) in order to reduce the size of the repositories by removing the biggest folders and graphic source files. It all worked on my computer, but when I want to upload to the git-server (after a looooong wait) I see the directories and files are still there!

I've tried using `git repack` to make sure the packs are also smaller and cloning the repository into a new folder, and it worked for the shrinking part of my problem, but when I went on with the `git branch -m trunk master` I received errors like:

```
1: error: refname refs/heads/trunk not found
2: fatal: Branch rename failed
3: error: src refspec master does not match any.
4: error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{username}/{projectname}'
```

I made a new commit for error #3, as explained on [the following reply on a topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5802508/1613810), but I had no progress what-so-ever...

I realize the errors are all connected together, but I don't understand why there's no trunk in the (local)cloned repository or why I suddenly have a couple of branches when I had just one `master`-branch in the other repos...

```
* [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD
* [new branch]      origin/master -> origin/master
```

To make a long story of a lot of tries, shorter:

> 1. I do a `git svn clone --no-metadata -A -stdLayout` to a new folder (`projectname`) with all history
>
>    1b. I remove all the obsolete folders and files (defined per repository)
> 2. I `git init` into a new repository (let's name it `projectname-copy`)
> 3. I push everything into a `bare` repository I created using `git init --bare bare-repo`
> 4. I try to upload to the hosted server, but I receive errors or no changes

Now my question is: does anybody have a solution for shrinking the repositories in size (local and remotely) and make it possible to upload them to my git-server?

PS: I think you'll know that writing commandline isn't my cup of tea, so please don't shoot me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it myself.

I made a local clone, did a `git repack -A -d`, followed by a `git gc --prune=now && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` and then I made a bare repo.

I had to check if the branches were correct, if not I made them with `git branch -m [branchname]` and then I could upload to my hosting.

Thought I'd share it with you guys `:-)`