# git push to GitHub repository branch gives error "src refspec master does not match any"

Tags: git, github

I forked the Flask repository and cloned its website branch from GitHub like

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/lovesh/flask.git -b website
```

Then i configured remote like

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/lovesh/flask.git -t website
git fetch upstream
```

Then i made the changes(i didnt create any additional files but modified 2 files) i had to make then added the files and committed the changes like this

```
git add .
git commit .
```

This prompted me for a comment for the commit and i entered the comment. Now it showed me

```
2 files changed, 69 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
```

But when i try to push these changes to my GitHub account

```
git push origin master
```

it shows the error

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/lovesh/flask.git'
```

I looked around and people who had this issue said that they did not commit the changes as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802426/535962). But i did commit even then it shows me this error.
To confirm i tried

```
git status
```

and it showed

```
# On branch website
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/website' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Also `git log` also shows my commit in the log. I am new to git. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have a master branch after cloning your repo.
[`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) details:

```
--branch <name>
-b <name>
```

> Instead of pointing the newly created `HEAD` to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository's `HEAD`, point to `<name>` branch instead.
>   In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.
>   `--branch` can also take tags and detaches the `HEAD` at that commit in the resulting repository.

So in your case, if you want to create and track the local website branch to origin, you need to:

```
git push -u origin website
```

(after that, a simple `git push` will be enough: more on the push policies in "[git - `push current` vs. `push upstream` (tracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751319/git-push-current-vs-push-upstream-tracking/13751847#13751847)")

---

Your other remote '`upstream`' will also only track `upstream/website` branch:

The [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) documentation does mention:

> With `-t <branch>` option, instead of the default glob refspec for the remote to track all branches under the `refs/remotes/<name>/ namespace`, a refspec to track only `<branch>` is created.
>   You can give more than one `-t <branch>` to track multiple branches without grabbing all branches.

In your case, you are only tracking `upstream/website` (`+refs/heads/website:refs/remotes/upstream/website`) instead of the [default refspec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169390/6309) (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*`).

Answer (score 1):

Try `git push origin website`
May be you configured your master branch under this name. Try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But can you explain how did i configure my master branch under this name? Or is it that with `git push origin` i have to mention the name of the branch i am pushing to?